# Can not delete subdirectories in Subversion

Tags: android-studio, svn

I am using Subversion (svn, 1.8.8) with Android Studio (2.2.1) and I have accidentally added intermediate files to svn that I want to delete now, but this fails on the commit command.

For example I try to delete the following directory:

```
ad@TITAN:~/AndroidStudioProjects/SPHA$ svn delete app/build/intermediates/assets
ad@TITAN:~/AndroidStudioProjects/SPHA$ svn status
...
D       app/build/intermediates/assets
...
```

But when I try to commit it fails:

```
ad@TITAN:~/AndroidStudioProjects/SPHA$ svn commit
...
Deleting       app/build/intermediates/assets
...
Transmitting file data .........................svn: E160016: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E160016: Path 'app/build' not present
svn: E160016: Your commit message was left in a temporary file:
svn: E160016:    '/home/ad/AndroidStudioProjects/SPHA/svn-commit.2.tmp'
```

It says that 'app/build' is not present, that is correct because I already deleted and committed that directory successfully before (hoping that it would either delete recursively or would fail).

How can I get rid of all subdirectories and files of 'app/build'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved now, I am answering my own question. First I had to add the 'app/build' directory again with the --force option and then I could delete the entire 'app/build' directory. That did the trick.

I guess that a previous commit got interrupted and left the directory in an 'undefined' state.